# How to concatenate 3 images like a triangle using ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick

Tags: imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I have three images, a.jpg, b.jpg, c.jpg。

I want to concatenate them so they look like the follow:

[image]

I want to do this using one command. No tmp files generated.
How can I do this using IM/GM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way in ImageMagick is to use smush rather then append. Smush allows offsets.

Create images:

```
convert -size 250x250 xc:green green.png
convert -size 250x250 xc:black black.png
convert -size 250x510 xc:red red.png
```

Now combine them:

```
convert -background white red.png \
\( green.png black.png -smush 10 \) \
+smush 10 \
result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution - note though that **GrapicsMagick** lacks `smush` operator AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, that is because GraphicsMagick was an early offshoot of ImageMagick and the former has remain mostly static, while the latter has continued to develop.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the images are all the correct sizes, this is probably easiest:

```
convert -size 10x10 green.png xc:white black.png -append xc:white red.png -reverse +append result.png
```

[image]

That says... *"make the size of the little spacers 10x10. Load the green image, then make a white spacer, then load the black image and append them together vertically. Make another white spacer. Load the red image. Reverse the columns of images so the most recently added red column is at the left instead of the right, append the images side-by-side."*

I did it this way round (starting with the right side) because GraphicsMagick doesn't offer parentheses.

---

If the images are not already suitably sized, you would be looking at something more like this - still a single command:

```
convert -size 10x10                 \
    \( green.png -resize somehow \) \
    xc:white                        \
    \( black.png -resize somehow \) \
    -append                         \
    xc:white                        \
    \( red.png -resize somehow   \) \
    -reverse +append result.png
```

Comment: I had not heard of -reverse before @Mark Setchell

Comment: @Bonzo It's pretty handy when you need to build things in the wrong order, or you want to append images right-to-left or bottom-to-top when the `+append` and `-append` naturally go left-to-right and top-to-bottom! If you see what I mean ;-) You can also achieve the same effect using `-swap` multiple times.

Comment: Thinks for you answer. But if all images size are same. How to do?

Comment: That's what the second part shows you. Change the part that says `red.png -resize somehow` to `red.png -resize WxH\!` where W is the width you want and H is the height you want - presumably the sum of the heights of the green and black plus the 10px spacer.

Comment: Thanks. And one more question. What's meaning of `xc:white`?

Comment: `xc:` stands for X11 (which is the windowing system on Unix) Canvas, where a canvas is a thing you paint/draw on. So it just means a piece of blank image, coloured white in this case, and its size was set previously with `-size 10x10` which, being a setting, persists until changed.

Comment: `xc:` and `canvas:` are interchangeable and mean the same thing in ImageMagick as Mark Setchell has explained above. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/#solid

Answer (score 2):

One other way to do this in ImageMagick is just to composite the 3 images to the proper corners of a white background image.

Create images:

```
convert -size 250x250 xc:green green.png
convert -size 250x250 xc:black black.png
convert -size 250x510 xc:red red.png
```

Process:

```
convert -size 510x510 xc:white \
red.png -gravity northwest -composite \
green.png -gravity northeast -composite \
black.png -gravity southeast -composite \
result.png
```

[image]

Comment: **ImageMagick** is such a powerful tool - it allows you to tackle a problem from so many different angles - I love it. Nice approach!